# Select rows based on approximate value

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table with prices of some goods registered for some 
dates, such as:

```
        2014-01-10      $120
        2014-01-11      $121
        2014-01-13      $119
        2014-01-15      $118
```

I would like to create a view which would fill the missing 
prices, ie. quote the existing prices where available, and return the 
last known price if the price for a particular day is unknown, perhaps 
with a reasonable limit in case a product disappears from the market:

```
    2014-01-10      $120
    2014-01-11      $121
    2014-01-12      $121
    2014-01-13      $119
    2014-01-14      $119
    2014-01-15      $118
    2014-01-16      $118
    2014-01-17      $118
    2014-01-18      $118
    ..........
    2014-02-01      NULL
```

If it was a mere matter of calculating the price one time, I 
would probably use a function for that, but I need later to combine 
the figures with the data from other tables with a date being a common  
field.

```
    2014-01-10      $120    data a
    2014-01-11      $121    data b
    2014-01-12      $121    data c
    2014-01-13      $119    data d
    2014-01-14      $119    data e
    2014-01-15      $118    NULL
    2014-01-16      $118    NULL
    2014-01-17      $118    data f
    2014-01-18      $118    data g
```

Normally, on 12th, 14th, and after 15th, the price field would 
return NULL, which I want to avoid, as it would ruin calculations which 
use the data later on.

If you believe that a view construction is not the best 
solution here, I'd be grateful for pointing me in the right direction 
- as you can see, the databases are not a field of my deepest 
expertise. ;)

Comment: Frankly speaking, at the moment I do not even have an idea how to approach the problem. My SQL knowledge is not much deeper than basic select, insert and create view using select.

Comment: I think it would be best to do the query which returns null when no value is found and then fill in the values in application logic. You're going to be looping over the data anyways. Sort on date, and grab the price from each row when it's non-null. When you see a null value, swap it for the last one you've seen.

Comment: Do you have a table of all the dates?

Comment: Not yet, but I can create it, if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all the dates that you care about, then you can use a correlated subquery to get the price:

```
select d.*,
       (select p.price
        from prices p
        where p.date <= d.date
        order by p.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as price
from dates d;
```

This is MySQL view-compatible -- the subquery is in the `select` clause rather than in the `from` clause.

Comment: Wow... it works. :) 
It took me a while to understand, how it works, but then I managed to extend it to include also a type of product. Now I have something to work out. Thanks.